# Independent increment property

Tags: probability-theory, independence

$X=(X_k, k \geq 0)$ is defined recursively by $X_0=1$ and $X_{k+1}=(1+X_k)U_k$ where $U_0,U_1,\ldots$ are independent random variables each uniformly distriubted on $[0,1]$.

Determine if the process has Maringale property and also Independent increment property.

My attempt:

$X_{k+1}-X_k= U_k+ X_k(U_k-1)$ and similarly, $X_{k+2}-X_{k+1}=U_{k+1}+(1+X_k)U_k(U_{k+1}-1)$ thus both the increments are dependent on $X_k$.

Can I conclude from here that the increments are not independent ? What's a more rigorous or exact way using definition of independence to prove the same ?